# Pip3 script not executed by Systemd

Tags: shell-script, systemd, python3

EDIT: As suggested I change it to direct path and directly calling python3 script to run instead of sh.
I am not able to run python script through systemd in linux. Do you see any problem in the steps below?

If I am running code directly from terminal, it is working:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dump1090exporter/dump1090exporter
```

I have python3 script with following body as dump1090-exporter - [https://github.com/claws/dump1090-exporter:](https://github.com/claws/dump1090-exporter)

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys

from dump1090exporter.__main__ import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw?|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

My systemd script:

```
[Unit]
Description=dump1090export

[Service]
Type=idle
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dump1090exporter/dump1090exporter
Restart=always
RestartSec=3

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If I am using `journalctl -u dump1090export` here is response:

```
Mar 29 02:53:56 homebridge-tman systemd[1]: Started dump1090export.
Mar 29 02:53:56 homebridge-tman python3[26168]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Mar 29 02:53:56 homebridge-tman python3[26168]:   File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dump1090exporter/dump1090exporter",
Mar 29 02:53:56 homebridge-tman python3[26168]:     from dump1090exporter.__main__ import main
Mar 29 02:53:56 homebridge-tman python3[26168]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dump1090exporter'
Mar 29 02:53:56 homebridge-tman systemd[1]: dump1090export.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Mar 29 02:53:56 homebridge-tman systemd[1]: dump1090export.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Mar 29 02:53:59 homebridge-tman systemd[1]: dump1090export.service: Service RestartSec=3s expired, scheduling restart.
Mar 29 02:53:59 homebridge-tman systemd[1]: dump1090export.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 116159.
```

Result of `systemctl status dump1090export`

```
● dump1090export.service - dump1090export
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/dump1090export.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2021-03-29 11:26:34 CEST; 788ms ago
  Process: 4473 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dump1090exporter/dump1090exporter (code=exited, 
 Main PID: 4473 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Where is `dump1090exporter` located, and is that place part of the standard `PATH`?  If not, you may want to refer to `dump1090exporter` with its full path.

Comment: Another thing: with `sh /usr/bin/dump1090export.sh` the executable is `sh`, so `dump1090export.sh` does not need to be executable. With `ExecStart=` it's different, I think. What is the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/dump1090export.sh`?

Comment: What does `journalctl -u dump1090export` tell you? What does `systemctl status dump1090export` say?

Comment: `ls -l /usr/bin/dump1090export.sh` returns `-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 140 Mar 24 12:17 /usr/bin/dump1090export.sh`

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute path to dump1090exporter or just pass executable and flags directly to ExecStart..